# Getting values from several set inside dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

i am making a function that would create a union of sort, for a value if you enter it inside the function it self:

```
dict = {"Mike" : {"shovel", "ball", "pool"}, 
        "Betty" : {"ball", "chair", "basket"}}

def bought_next(customers, item):
    for i in customers:
        value_unit = set()
        if item in customers[i]:
            value1 = customers[i]
            value1.remove(item)
            value_unit |= value1

    return value_unit
```

To explain a little further, my intention is to make a set in which all the items will be equal to the items purchased by all the customers that have purchased item entered into the function, minus that item of course. Now i may be working this entirely into the wrong direction but i am left with out ideas as to how to solve this issue, because with this, it simply keeps returning the empty set.

Comment: could you provide desired result for clarity?

Comment: and have you tried to print something inside the `if`

Comment: yeah ofc, my bad: the desired result would be: e.g. item = ball so there fore the out put set would be {"shovel", "chair", "pool", "basket"}

Comment: there is no change, it doesnt even get to the if... waw, i am dense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your code is that you reset `value_unit = set()` for each customer in turn. So your result will only ever be the result applicable to the "last" customer, not all customers combined.

For your example data, your code in fact does *not* return an empty set, it returns (for me) `set(['basket', 'chair'])` in Python 2 and `{'shovel', 'pool'}` in Python 3. So as an aside, the two different versions of Python have iterated over the dictionary in different orders.

In any case, you're probably better removing the item at the end than removing it each time. Your current code modifies the dictionary passed in, which probably isn't expected. For example you could get the result you want like this:

```
def bought_next(customers, item):
    value_unit = set()
    for values in customers.values():
        if item in values:
            value_unit |= values
    return value_unit - {item}
```

Comment: ok moving it out of the for loop doesnt change anything, i tried.

Comment: @Jervis: moving it out of the loop fixes it for me. You should look more closely at your test code: you're reporting that it returns empty sets when it shouldn't, and that a change makes no difference when it should. Is your test code *identical* to the code you've posted, or is there some difference that explains why you're not seeing the same results that I'm seeing by running the code you posted?

Comment: i literaly copied your code and it still returns set(). i do have edition 4.5.4 if that helpse or changes anything

Comment: @Jervis: how strange. I'll look into it further if you post your complete code in the question, including the call to `bought_next` and whatever print statement shows you your result.

Comment: ok forgive my density, i was watching the wrong thing. it helped! thx a million times, i have no ideas what i messed up, aside from that value part, because it never dropped on my mind to try that- again, thx

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need something like this:

```
bought = {"Mike" : {"shovel", "ball", "pool"}, 
        "Betty" : {"ball", "chair", "basket"}}

def bought_next(customers, item):
    return {c: s - {item} for c, s in bought.items() if c in customers}
```

The result:

```
In [6]: bought_next(['Mike', 'Betty'], 'ball')
Out[6]: {'Betty': {'basket', 'chair'}, 'Mike': {'pool', 'shovel'}}
```

By the way, it is considered a bad practice to override keywords, like `dict`

Edit 1:
OK, after you provided result, there is corrected code:

```
import itertools

bought = {"Mike" : {"shovel", "ball", "pool"}, 
        "Betty" : {"ball", "chair", "basket"}}

def bought_next(customers, item):
    other_then_item = [s - {item} for c, s in bought.items() if c in customers]
    return set(itertools.chain(*other_then_item))
```

Edit 2.
Yeah, solution provided by Steve Jessop is more concise, since it removes item in resulting set. This is a bit better:

```
def bought_next(customers, item):
    all_items = [s for c, s in bought.items() if c in customers]
    return set(itertools.chain(*all_items)) - {item}
```

Comment: yes but thats not what im going for here. i just get as a result the dictionary without teh item i put in. what i need is a set of items that people that bought that item also bought.